# Custom dimension data not showing in analytics (using google tag manager)

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I've been following numerous implementation guides on this feature and have yet to see the final result. What i'm trying to do is very standard: Add a custom dimension called User type to UA. My site uses Google Tag Manager.

Here are my implementation steps:

1. Created a custom dimension in UA
   [image]
2. Created a Data Layer Variable name userType
   [image]
3. Added the dimension to my Analytics page view tag

[image]

4. Added the following code to page load:

```js
var dimensionValue =$('#user_type').data('type');
dataLayer.push({'userType': dimensionValue});
```

5. Published the tag manager changes
6. When debugging through tag manager I see the following output:

[image]

7. All looks legit right? So, why oh why, when I go to my custom report, do I see this:

[image]

I'd be grateful for any idea as to what the problem might be.

Thanks,

Uri

Comment: Are you checking right away with your reports or are you giving some time for the data to process, which takes about 24 hours?

Comment: It's been a few hours... Not 24 though

Comment: OK i  suggest to give it more time. You can check every few hours, but don't start panicking until it's been more than 24 hours, or sometimes more. ;)

Comment: Thanks for following up. Sorry to say that there's still no data :-/

Comment: Use the [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) and verify that the custom dimension is fired with an hit.

Comment: In the google analytics debugger it indeed shows the dimension value is undefined. But in the GTM debugger it has the correct value. Any idea why the difference?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to combine user based dimension and hit based metric. Try other metrics for your report

Comment: Tried it with Avg. sessions duration, no data as well. That's a user based metric right?

Comment: Try to change scope of your custom dimension. For example, session scope with avg. session duration.

Comment: Do you push dimension value to dataLayer before GTM container or after?

Comment: I might have pushed to data Layer before GTM has been initialized, even though the dataLayer variable exists at the time of pushing so it sounds weird.. I'm trying to change to order of the rows.